# installing rgl in amazon web services

Tags: r, installation

I have a problem installing rgl package in amazon web services using an AMI for rstudio.
I'm completely ignorant about how using rstudio on aws, i need to run a code once and stop it.
Unfortunately i'm trying installing rgl package,aws doesn't allow X11 so im wondering how to avoid this error:

```
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/634584/how-to-set-up-a-desktop-gui-with-an-amazon-ec2-instance  And this does seem like a question which is more appropriate for ServerFault anyway.

Comment: It really is the same as the question I listed (and dozen others like it):  you do not have X11, cannot add it -- but can 'pretend' you have via prepending `xvfb-run`.